# 301 Error : Lost data POST

Tags: php, forms, post

I've a 301 error after doing my POST Form...
When I submit my form, I lose all my data and I don't know why.
I search on the net but I don't understand anything because my english is too bad to do it...

My HTML code :

```
<form action="../../controler/add/addSwitchPort.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Switch</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class='switchName' name="switchName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="buttonIndex" type="submit" name='vlan' value="Add & vlan" style="width:200px"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My PHP code :

```
<?php
$switchName = $_POST['switchName'];

echo $switchName;
echo '???';

$bra = addSwitchPort($switchName);
```

Do you know why the `echo` is empty ? There is no way because this is the right location !

Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: your form is working fine. it is error in your action url

Comment: but the `echo '???'` is wrote in my screen... So it's the right location

Comment: i check this form with not action it working perfectly so no problem in form

Comment: your `<form>` does end right?

Comment: yes it does. I just deleted a lot of rows to make my code more simple to understand ^^'

Comment: Do you have any idea ?